# How to render progress bar while using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

Edit: what is the point of instant downvotes...

This is the effect I am trying to recreate:

[image]

When you click on a button, it has a progress bar inside the button. I made it in vanilla js but wanted to recreate this project with react + hooks.

Here is code sandbox of what the project structure looks like: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-euclid-wf00z

I have an array of objects that contains what the buttons are:

```
const buttons = [
  {
    name: "build box",
    duration: 3 // takes 3 seconds to complete
  },
  {
    name: "test button",
    duration: 5
  }
];
```

This is the parent component that renders the buttons:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {buttons.map(btn => (
        <Button name={btn.name} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And finally, this is the button component:

```
const Button = props => {
  const [progressPercentage, setProgressPercentage] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="button-container">
      <div
        style={{ width: progressPercentage + "%" }}
        className="button-progress"
      />
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Im pretty sure the right way to do this is with a mixture of useState and useEffect hooks. Each button will keep track of its own state and set the width of the progress bar to the `progressPercentage`.

But maybe itll be better to use a setInterval to calculate the amount of time that has been passed.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: in vanilla javascript did you do it with css ?

Comment: No. I just adjusted the width using js in relation to the progress. Cant use CSS to achieve what im trying to do because buttons get unmounted and remounted. If a button takes 1 minute and gets unmounted, when it gets remounted, it needs to still have the same progress state

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best way to do it, but this might work:

Edit: Made it work in the sandbox.

```js
const Button = props => {
  const step = 1
  const interval = 10
  const maxProgress = 100

  const [progressPercentage, setProgressPercentage] = useState(100);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateProgress = () => setProgressPercentage(progressPercentage + step)
    if (progressPercentage < maxProgress) {
      setTimeout(updateProgress, interval)
    }
  }, [progressPercentage])

  return (
    <div className="button-container" onClick={() => setProgressPercentage(0)}>
      <div
        style={{ width: progressPercentage + "%" }}
        className="button-progress"
      />
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use some animation library to achieve this. I made an example using framer-motion in https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-snowflake-9tbfb.